# How to find screen coordinates of a smaller image within a screenshot

Tags: ruby, image-processing

How do you get the coordinates of a image that exists within a screenshot?

I have a screen shot that looks like this. (partial)

[image: progresss bar]

and I would like to find out the coordinates of the progress indicator

[image: progress indicator]

and the play button

[image: play button]

My script is written in ruby and I am running OSX 10.7

Is there anything that exists that can do this?

If a brute force search is needed whats the best language to do this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the target size then use **brute force attack** ...

- this is pretty basic shape/pattern
- so if the size is known it is quite easy and not too slow ...

1.**find possible locations**

- create control points to check for possible location of your button
- they should describe your image to discard most invalid loactions
- something like this:

[image: control points]

- red dots are the control points
- the less tne number of points the faster it will be
- but also less precise ...
- now just go through entire screen and compute

  ```
  maxdiff = max(|scrpnt(i)-ctrlpnt(i)|)
  avgdiff = sum(|scrpnt(i)-ctrlpnt(i)|) / n
  ```
- n - is number of control points (in picture n = 11)
- i = 0,1,2...n-1
- if both maxdiff and avgdiff < treshold then this is possible location on button

2.**test possible location**

- now do the check for all points of possible location arrea
- if both maxdiff and avgdiff < treshold then this is button location
- if the image is big enough you can speed it up by testing not all pixels at first
- but with some step ... for example:

  - first test with step = 8px
  - if it pass then step = 1px

[Notes]

- I do not code for your platform so I can not consider language but any with pixel access will do
- I saw few similar questions here on SE in past
- so if you search a bit you will probably find some solutions (try pattern recognition)